# What does "Argument #1 is not an array in _form_set_class()" mean?

Tags: 7

In Drupal 7, I'm getting this error and want to fix it:

> - Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in _form_set_class() (line 4021 of {my site}/includes/form.inc).
> - Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in _form_set_class() (line 4021 of {my site}/includes/form.inc).
> - Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in theme_radios() (line 2746 of {my site}/includes/form.inc).

What does this mean, and what should I do about it?

Comment: What you did do cause the error would be most helpful to know.

Comment: I had the same problem, when I uninstalled the module Custom Breadcrumbs (7.x-1.x-dev) and reinstalled again, it was solved.

Answer (score 10):

For me it happened; when I used

`$form['field']['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'myclass');`

While it should be

`$form['field']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('myclass'));`

Answer (score 1):

There's likely a buggy FAPI definition. Are you developing a form? If so, check your form definition. It's not being returned as an array.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out, I wasn't sure what I had done to make this start happening, but it was being caused by the "Drupal for Facebook" module. It was only popping up when I was on a node edit page strangely. For those familiar, I had the "FB User Management" enabled and after disabling, it stopped giving me the error.